# How do I create objects using more than one constructor?

Tags: java

I wrote the following code and driver program but I am not sure how to create bank account objects using both constructors. One constructor takes an initial balance and the second constructor opens an account with no money. Also, should the accountBalance include validity checks?

Optionally, I could do the following:

Include a fee as part of what describes a bank account. Update the BankAccount class as necessary. The user should be able to set the fee amount for each account and add the fee through a method. Add code to the driver program to demonstrate the fee functionality. (Could someone explain to me what this is asking)

```
//Bank Account class   
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class BankAccount {

private String ownerName;
private String accountId;
private double accountBalance;

public BankAccount(String ownerName, String accountId, double accountBalance) {
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.accountId = accountId;
    if(accountBalance >= 0) { 
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;           
    } else {
        System.out.println("Due to your negative account balace, you will be issued a fee.\n");
    }
}

public BankAccount(double accountBalance) {
    accountBalance = 0;
}

public String getOwnerName() {
    return ownerName;
}

public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
}

public String getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
}

public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

public double getAccountBalance() {
    return accountBalance;
}

public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
    if(accountBalance >= 0) { 
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;           
    } else {
        System.out.println("Due to your negative account balace, you will be issued a fee.\n");
    }
}

public void withdraw(double amount) { 
    if(amount > 0 && amount < accountBalance) { 
        accountBalance -= amount;           
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid withdraw amount! Please try again.\n");
    }
}

public void deposit(double amount) { 
    if(amount > 0) { 
        accountBalance += amount;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid deposit amount! Please try again.\n");
    }
}

public String toString() { 
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    return "Account Owner's Name: " + ownerName + "\n" + "Account ID: " + accountId + "\n" + 
           "Balance in the account: " + currencyFormatter.format(accountBalance);
}
}

//Driver Program
public class BankAccountDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount("Smith", "123jahgsd", 1200);                      
    myAccount.withdraw(0.453);
    myAccount.deposit(1000.1);
    System.out.println(myAccount);
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but both of the constructors of `BankAccount` include an opening balance. You need to be *really* clear when asking a question - it should be specific, and only one question per post.

Comment: *Also, should the accountBalance include validity checks?* what type of checks? postive, zero, or negative balances are OK is my opinion

Comment: Just for the record: i updated the answer again to talk a bit about the validation topic of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All nice answers, but they actually "miss" the "real" issue; and that is: you don't put down constructors because you *can*.

You create the code that is required to fulfill your requirements. In other words: you step back; and you **think up** respectively *design* the "intended use cases" for your bank account class.

And things to consider there: you **avoid** classes that can be created using such **different** paths.

Example: it is extremely dangerous to allow for **empty** id / owner fields. That leaves those fields with `null` values; and that means that you either need a lot of checking here and there; and if you forgot that here or there; you will run into NullPointerExceptions sooner or later (rather soon).

And keep in mind: your objects are meant to **represent** (model!) "reality". In reality, a bank account doesn't go without an owner; or an id.

In that sense, a **sane** implementation of your class would much more look like:

```
public class BankAccount {
  private final String owner;
  private final String id;
  private double currentBalance;

  public BankAccount(String owner, String id) {
    this(ownwer, id, 0);
  }

  public BankAccount(String owner, String id, double currentBalance) {
    this.owner = owner;
    ...
```

Notes here:

- You want to prevent owner/id to be changed, so you make them final; and thus you also don't have **setter** methods for those fields
- In a real world solution, you would not use Strings to represent names or ids, but distinct classes
- You would also **never ever** use `double` to represent **currency**. This is a superbasic thing: **money** should not be represented using floating point numbers! (You would be looking towards to the BigDecimal class; or simply using **int** instead of double (and represent 1.75 $ as 175 cent)
- And just a glance of real real world: nowadays, you don't model a bankaccount to have a "current balance". Instead, a bank account might be affiliated to a **history** of events (denoting deposits and pay-off transactions).

Final point: for your current exercise, that kind of "validation" for withdrawl/deposit is "okay"; in the "real world" validation would probably happen in many other places, too. (coming back to my initial statement: it all depends on your model; a simple model could say that a bank account itself is "validating" things; but a more realistic solution is that you have other components that deal with "rules", "laws" and all kinds of topics that do "validation").

Comment: very good points, however maybe the `owner` should be able to change

Comment: Largely agreed; but I'd say a cleaner design than "telescoping" the constructors is just to have one constructor, taking the name and id. Then just use the deposit method afterwards to set the balance.

Comment: Understood! Thank you for clarifying that confusion:)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Maybe for this exercise here; but well; in the real world, bank accounts do not change owners. You move money from one account to another, but not the whole account.

Comment: Yeah, my wife had an account like that, and she could not change the name when she got married.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think that could debated lengthy. For me, the crucial point is: when you have **more than one** constructor, than you do telescoping. Having constructors that do independent things is already an indication that your class should probably be splitted into those two parts.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Well, that is where "how to model" the owner kicks in. Actually you would not use the "owner name", but some "owner id" field there; and that should be definitely be final ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! But would it be ok to add a validation to accountBalance as not being negative if I want to include an overdraft fee? I edited my code above implementing the validation but do you mind explaining what this instruction means: "Include a fee as part of what describes a bank account. The user should be able to set the fee amount for each account and add the fee through a method."

Comment: @ally Sure. In the end, this is "exercise" code. But still you could consider putting such logic **outside** of your Account class. You could create a class "WithdrawlValidator" that receives a BankAccount object and some withdraw request. Then *that* validator class contains the rules/knowledge to determine if the withdraw is legit; and it could also return that "fee" to you. So, your code asks the validator: "can I deduct X for account Y"; and the validator then tells you "yes/no"; and provides the information about the appropriate fee, too.

Answer (score 1):

You make objects depending on which constructor you want to use. For example, to use the first constructor you need three parameters like so,

```
BankAccount first = new BankAccount("Bob", "ID45", 400.50);
```

and to use the second constructor you only need one parameter, the balance, like so,

```
BankAccount second = new BankAccount(400.50);
```

They'll both make instances of `BankAccount` except the difference is that on creation, the first bank account will have fields `ownerName` and `accountId` filled out while the second bank account will have those fields set to empty String values. However, the second object will have a balance of 0 unlike the first object's balance of 400.5

**EDIT:** Like user ScaryWombat suggested, there is a flaw in your second constructor because if you want to define an object with a balance of 0 then there's no point in adding a `balance` parameter. Also, in this case it would be advisable to give default values to your other fields as well,

```
public BankAccount() {
    ownerName = "unknown";
    accountId = "unknown";
    accountBalance = 0;
}
```

So now when you create an instance of `BankAccount` with this constructor, it'll have the default values, "unknown", "unknown", and 0.

```
BankAccount third = new BankAccount();
```

Also, for the `fee` part, all you have to do is not only create another field in your `BankAccount` class called `fee` but also make a setter method to allow the user to set its fee,

```
private double fee;
.
.
.
public void setFee (double fee) {
   this.fee = fee;
}
```

And in the main method, the user can access it with the following,

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Fred", "ID145", 400);
account.setFee(15); //this will set the fee to 15
```

Comment: @ally This is correct.  However, I might add that your second constructors parameter is pointless.  You are setting account balance to 0.  Why put a parameter there?

Comment: @RSon1234 true just edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This is bad behavior to have `BankAccount second = new BankAccount(400.50);` and then have the `accountBalance` being 0

Comment: @ScaryWombat True, but this is how OP defined the constructor, not Chris

Comment: @ScaryWombat good point I edited my answer to make note of this. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
   public BankAccount(String ownerName, String accountId, double accountBalance) {
       this.ownerName = ownerName;
       this.accountId = accountId;
       this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
   }

   public BankAccount() {
       this("some default name", "some default id", 0.0);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a BankAccount with a zero balance then

```
public BankAccount(String ownerName, String accountId, double accountBalance) {
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
}

public BankAccount() {
    this.accountBalance = 0;
}
```

You can instantiate them as

```
BankAccount mine = new BankAccount("Scary", "123", 1000000.00);
BankAccount empty = new BankAccount();
```

**edit**

If you choose to construct a method with the second method, the `id` and `owner` would also be `null` and maybe not very useful

Comment: "with zero balance" yes, but that also creates it with null id and owner name.

Comment: @AndyTurner Agree not very useful. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create one bank account object using *both* constructors. You only call one of the two constructors to create a new object. So you either do:

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Sweeper", "ABCDEF", 10000);
```

or:

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount(100000);
```

Note that your second constructor's parameter is pointless because you initialize the balance to 0 no matter what the parameter is:

```
public BankAccount(double accountBalance) {
    accountBalance = 0;
}
```

I think this makes more sense:

```
public BankAccount() {
    this.accountBalance = 0;
}
```

As for your second question, I will give you some tips.

You need to add a new field to the class, called `fee`. Add getters and setters for it.

Comment: You are the only one that answered _How to create objects using **more than one constructor**?_

Comment: I guess I was confused about the requirements that: One constructor takes an initial balance and the second constructor opens an account with no money. I thought that I had to initialize the balance to zero.